# Call functions from a slice with functions and get return value(s)

Tags: go, slice

I'm transpiling some Python / Javascript to Go and having issues with 1 last thing.

In py / js I'm calling a function from an array while I loop over the indexes.

Python:

```py
 n = [compareUserAgent, hashUserAgent, hashLanguage]
    o = seed
    u = 0
    while u < t:
        o ^= (n[getNext() % len(n)](u,seed))
        u += 1
```

Javascript:

```js
for (var n = [compareUserAgent, hashUserAgent, hashLanguage], a, o = a.seed, u = 0; u < t; u++) {
        o ^= (0, n[a.getNext() % n.length])(u, a.seed)
    }
```

As you can see, it creates an array of functions and calls them.
I've tried to replicate this with doing something like:

```golang
n := make([]interface{}, 3)

n[0] = CompareUserAgent
n[1] = HashUserAgent
n[2] = HashLanguage
    
o := seed

for u := 0; u < t; u++ {

    o ^= (n[GetNext() & len(n)](u, seed))
}
```

But I'm getting this error: `cannot call non-function n[GetNext() & len(n)] (type interface {})`

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The elements of `n` are of type `interface{}`, which is not a function type. Remember, unlike JavaScript and Python, Go is a statically-typed language; you can only treat a value as the type it has defined. Since it appears these functions all share the same signature, this shouldn't be a problem; just do something like the following, with the argument & return types adapted (since they aren't shown in your question I'm just using `int`s in this example):

```
type myFn func(int,int) int
n := []myFn{CompareUserAgent,HashUserAgent,HashLanguage}
    
o := seed

for u := 0; u < t; u++ {
    o ^= (n[GetNext() & len(n)](u, seed))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are defining your array of functions. You are declaring them as `interface{}` which are not callables.

Instead you need to define them as following:

```
type hasher func(int, int) int
n := make([]hasher, 3)
```

Comment: Made a mistake when copy/pasting. Now I removed the extra `{}`